# Issue with open syscall in /tmp folder with uid 0

Tags: linux, filesystems, system-calls, tmp

I have conducted a small test which raised an issue i could not figure out.

1. Create file in `/tmp` named `what` as shell user (uid 1000), then make it `0666` (rw-rw-rw-)
2. Try to call `open` with uid 0 (root) in the following format: `open("/tmp/what", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);`

And for my surprise, the syscall failed with errno "Permission denied", although i'm running as root.

So i tried to do the exact opposite, create the file as root, then chmod it to 0666, and try to call `open` the same way but with uid 1000, and for some reason it WORKED.

I tried to re-create the issue in other directories but found no success, meaning it had something to do with `/tmp`

But the more interesting thing was that if i were to remove the `O_CREAT` flag it resolves the issue, although i have no idea why since this flag is considered if and only if the file does not exist, I'm quite sure i'm missing something...

Would love for some assistance.

Comment: Yes, i'll research further, but thanks! 

Although i don't understand why was the restriction added upon calling `open` with `O_CREAT`